# Variable Webfont not loading in Safari

Tags: safari, webfonts

I have a Variable font that I'm loading from my own server

Sometimes in Safari (Only Safari) the font doesn't load and I get the backup font.

If I look in the Dev tools > Network > Font it says

```
Failed to load resource: Origin --- is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

If I clear the browser cache and reload the page the correct web font loads.

Does anyone know or have any ideas why this might be happening

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not much information available to debug this issue.
You can follow these approaches to fix your issue:

- When using custom font make sure you included all the formats in the `@font-face`

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Fira Sans";
 src: url('fonts/fira/eot/FiraSans-Regular.eot');
 src: url('fonts/fira/eot/FiraSans-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('fonts/fira/woff2/FiraSans-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('fonts/fira/woff/FiraSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('fonts/fira/woff2/FiraSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

- You can also `preload` your custom font
  Add this to  in the HTML `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="fonts/some-font.woff2">
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works correctly once after a hard-reload, and then fails with a CORS error, it's probably a redirect error.

The first time around, the browser requests the font resource (url) cleared by your server's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so even if that resources redirects to another resource, it gets past your CORS rule.

But the second time and thereon, the browser makes direct requests to the redirected resource using the cached address, which is not in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Other browers allow this, but Safari doesn't. So you will have to add the second resource's origin to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, or serve the webfont directly from one of the origins that are already on the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a CORS error. Are your fonts loaded from a different domain than your application? In this case, the URL of your application needs to be specified as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server response that returns your fonts.

Note that `localhost` on two different ports are considered to be two different domains, from a CORS perspective.

More info [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/08/02/fix-common-problems-cors).